# nvd3 displaying large black dots, and not fully rendering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to create a line chart using d3.js and [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/), but I keep getting a rendering error, which seems to be causing several elements to be draw incorrectly, or not at all.

The error that shows up in the error console is `Error: Problem parsing d="MZ"`

After looking in the code of nvd3, I found that the code joins a list of vertices, using `L`, (so an example of a correct point would be `d="M0 0L1 1L1 0Z`)

My code for creating the graph is:

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
  var chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
    .x(function (d) {
    return d[0]
  })
    .y(function (d) {
    return d[1]
  })
    .showControls(false)
    .showLegend(false);

  d3.select('#mygraph')
    .datum(data2)
    .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

An example of the error is online [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sssv7/).

Comment: This is a bug in nvd3: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/pull/62

Answer (score 4):

The `CSS` is missing (from [here](http://nvd3.org/src/nv.d3.css)).
I've updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sssv7/2/.
You must add the CSS or add your own classes to customize how it looks like.